# Elegant way to replace values across dataframe without column names

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [101,101,101,101],
                        'start_date':['NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA','Nil','06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM'],
                        'desc':['-','- ',' - ','test-date'],
                        'type':['test-date','actual-version','depat-head','oxygen-parlor']})
```

I would like to replace the values `NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA`, `Nil`, `-` with `np.nan`

I tried the below

```
df.replace(['NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA','Nil','-', np.nan)
df.dropna(subset=['person_id','start_date','desc','type'], how='any')
```

Though the above works to an extent, it is not accurate because it doesn't consider hyphens with spaces `-`  or  `-` etc. Please note that the `-` in `type` column SHOULD NOT BE REPLACED.

Can help me replace exact values (but with exceptions of space characters) across dataframe but without using column names?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
person_id              start_date               desc           type
  101               06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM    test-date    oxygen-parlor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a replacement on the entire data frame using a regex alternation:

```py
terms = ['NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA', 'Nil', '-']
regex = r'^\s*(?:' + '|'.join(terms) + r')\s*$'
df = df.replace(regex, np.nan, regex=True)
```

The regex pattern used here is `^\s*(?:NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA|Nil|-)\s*$`, and will only match the `NA` string, `-` ,and `Nil` when they are the entire content of a column (but not a substring only).

Comment: thanks, upvoted. When you mean `entire content of a column`, does it consider `spaces` as well?

Comment: @TheGreat I didn't see that edge case, but I just snuck in an update which will also match `-` (or the other two) when they are surrounded by leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: fantastic. I see the difference. Good to know and learn regex from you experts. will accept the answer soon

Comment: Hi, one minor question. I was trying the below `terms = ['NA-NA-NA NA:NA:NA', 'Nil', '-']
regex = r'^\s*(?:' + '|'.join(terms) + r')\s*$'
rte = [np.nan,np.nan,'no_info']
df.replace(terms, rte,regex=True)` but for some reason, it does;n't work. can't I replace multiple values with multiple values (instead of a single value)?

Comment: No.  (Almost) all regex replacements API use a single replacement value.  There might be some tricks you could use, but typically you would just do multiple replacements.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.replace(regex=['Nil|NA|^-'], value=np.nan).dropna()
```

```
         person_id              start_date       desc           type
3        101            06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM  test-date  oxygen-parlor
```

Comment: Sorry, had missed bits, edited. However, you are better of searching the dataframe where the charcters exist. Reverse the selection and mask. Code is:- `df[~df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('^\-').any(), axis=1)]`